# need to sort this result by Length then limit 2 : db.films.find ({$or:[{"Special Features": "Commentaries"}, {toInt(Length:{$gt: 25})}]}).limit(2);

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to sort the results of below by Length (minutes in a film converted to int), then want to limit the results to longest 2.

```js
db.films.find(
  {$or:[{"Special Features": "Commentaries"},
        {toInt(Length:{$gt: 25})}
       ]
  }
).limit(2);
```

I tried above, but gives me top 2 documents in collection, rather than top 2 of the results returned before adding `.limit(2)`
Believe I need to sort by Length (string toInt) before adding `.limit(2)` having trouble.

Comment: Would you show an example document?

Comment: But your query doesn't contain sort, that's why the result return without sorting. Probably you are looking for: `db.films.find(...).sort({ "Length": -1 }).limit(2)`